# Duplicate layer and move it

Tags: ios, calayer, caanimation

I want to create an animation which "create a copy of a view, move this copy from a point to another point while decreasing opacity until it totally disappear".

I suppose i need to do it through a `CABasicAnimation` so i tried something like that :

```
    CGPoint point = CGPointMake(200, 0);

    // copy layer
    CALayer *layer = [[CALayer alloc] initWithLayer:self.animatedView.layer];
    [self.animatedView.layer addSublayer:layer];

    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    animation.fromValue = [layer valueForKey:@"position"];
    animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point];
    animation.duration = 2.0f;

    CABasicAnimation *oanimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    oanimation.fromValue = @1;
    oanimation.toValue = @0;
    oanimation.duration = 1.0f;

    // move copy layer
    [layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"position"];
    [layer addAnimation:oanimation forKey:@"opacity"];
```

But nothings append and i think it's a normal situation regarding to documentation :

> This initializer is used to create shadow copies of layers, for
>   example, for the presentationLayer method. Using this method in any
>   other situation will produce undefined behavior. For example, do not
>   use this method to initialize a new layer with an existing layer’s
>   content.

Someone already did this kind of animation before ?

Thx for your help.

Comment: Why a copy? And why a layer? Why not just move and fade the original view?

Comment: Because this is not what i want to do. I'm copying a view from left controller to a right controller (splitted screen) so I want an effect that fake a movement from left to right while remaining on left controller

Comment: Ok, so you want to copy, but you can still do that at view level. `UIView` conforms to `NSCoding` so you can copy it.

Comment: I said an UIView to generalize but it's actually an UITableViewCell. Could it work with it also ?

Comment: Sure, a standard table view will work easily. A custom subclass will take a little more effort. The main limitation of view copying is the targets and actions of controls will be lost and custom view classes probably won't respect the coding contracts.

Comment: I don't need targets and actions since it's an temporary copy, just to perform my animation. I'm doing the "real" copy in another way so it's good. I will try this, thx a lot !

Answer (score 1):

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(theView.frame.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[theView.layer renderInContext:context];
UIImage *screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:screenShot];
imgView.frame = theView.frame;
[self.view addSubview:imgView];
```

then play with 'imgView' :)

Comment: I find the answer to have some merit. I'd also add that If you want the rendered image to be Retina (@2x, @3x), you can replace the first line by this: `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(theView.frame.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)`

Answer (score 0):

## Solution 1: CALayers

I adapted @Sriram solution in Swift 4.2 and preferred to use a more adapted CALayer instead of an `UIImageView`.

```swift
// We use the screen's scale to support Retina displays
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(viewToCopy.frame.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
if let context: CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
    // We convert the layer of the viewToCopy into an UIImage
    viewToCopy.layer.render(in: context)
    let screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    
    // We create a layer that will hold the image. This layer can be animated further down the road.
    let layer = CALayer()
    layer.contents = screenshot?.cgImage // Don't forget .cgImage, otherwise it won't work
    layer.frame = viewToCopy.frame // For example
    view.layer.addSublayer(layer)
}
```

I guess this one works fine for most cases, but I’ve encountered some issues while doing this with a `UIVisualEffectView` (the effect broke). So I had to figure out a second solution.

## Solution 2: UIView Copy

First, you’re going to need a small extension to `UIView` to be able to copy it easily. I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34404432/4802021) but I’ll copy it here for clarity.

```swift
// MARK: - UIView + Copy

extension UIView {
    func copyView<T: UIView>() -> T {
        return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self)) as! T
    }
}
```

Once you have this, you can copy the view, add it and lay it out into your view hierarchy, and use it just like any other `UIView`.

```swift
let animationCardView = cardView.copyView()
animationCardView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addSubview(animationCardView)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([animationCardView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cardView.leadingAnchor),
                                     animationCardView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cardView.trailingAnchor),
                                     animationCardView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cardView.topAnchor),
                                     animationCardView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cardView.bottomAnchor)])
```